# Glassfish datasource implementation different then vendor (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, datasource, glassfish-3

I am trying to create a jdbc connection to a postgresql database. I would like to use a datasource. In the documentation of postgresql is stated that one should not use their own implementations of the datasource, but use the implementations of org.apache.commons.dbcp instead. The SharedPoolDatasource looks perfect to me.

The jdbc driver must be postgresql. Glassfish v3.1 offers the opportunity to create a jdbc connection pool. I would like to use that one, but do not know how to make the connection between the commons datasource implementation and the jdbc driver. When I fill in the document on the glassfish server that particular field blanks out forcing me to use the postgresql datasource implementation.

Is this impossible to achieve or do I have to enter data manually in config files? So far I did not have any luck nor feedback. Exceptions should appear in the server.log, but the server.log currently does not show anything (it did show exceptions deploying jsf and ejb applications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible....

**1. Create a new JDBC Connection Pool:**

[image]

**2. Choose your desired Datasource Implementation Class:**

[image]

**You'll have to setup the details for databasename, user and password in the additional properties tab.**

**3. Create a new JDBC Resource:**

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising. It is the one combination I did not try. I can execute it on monday, but I believe it will work already.